# IE vs Chrome new Date("22/22/22")

Tags: google-chrome, date, internet-explorer

In IE if you write in the console `new Date("22/22/22")` you get the answer of *Mon Oct 22 00:00:00 CDT 1923*

In Chrome it says *Invalid Date*.

What is happening here and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is happening here and why?

What's happening is you're running into undocumented behavior. The only string format the `Date` constructor is required to support is the ISO-8601 simplification in [the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-date-time-string-format), which your example does not match. Everything else is undocumented and JavaScript engines are at liberty to do whatever they want, including guessing at the format you're giving them (and doing JavaScript's nifty rollover when you take a value like 'month number' out of bounds), or giving you an invalid date.

If you're curious about the rollover, IE's treating that as the 22nd day of the 22nd month of the year 1922. Naturally, years don't have 22 months, but JavaScript's `Date` is defined as handling rollover in various fields, such as month number, gracefully. So the 22nd month of 1922 is actually the 10th month of 1923, and of course, you're on the 22nd day of it: October 22, 1923.

Comment: [The value produced by Date.parse is implementation-dependent when given any String value that does not conform to the Date Time String Format](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date.parse). So it's kinda documented that it's undocumented. I wouldn't rely on implementation-dependent implementations lol

Comment: @Austin: Yes, it's documented that it's undocumented. :-)

Answer (score -1):

IE 11 and Firefox 42 translates the value 22 for month to 12+10.
Chromium throws a error.

Different JS engine implementations gives different results for invalid values.